# Errors when sending data in body using Finagle/Finch in Scala

Tags: scala, rest, finagle, argonaut

I am using [Finagle/Finch](https://github.com/finagle/finch) and I get this error:

```
diverging implicit expansion for type argonaut.DecodeJson[A] starting 
  with method MapDecodeJson in trait DecodeJsons
diverging implicit expansion for type argonaut.DecodeJson[V] starting 
  with method MapDecodeJson in trait DecodeJsons
not enough arguments for method body: (implicit d: 
 io.finch.Decode.Aux[A,CT], implicit ct: 
 scala.reflect.ClassTag[A])io.finch.Endpoint[A]. Unspecified value 
 parameters d, ct.
```

For this code:

```
def sendPost(db: CommDb): Endpoint[String] =
  post("posts" :: body.as[String]) { s: String =>
    Ok("success")
  }
```

I have no idea how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `body` API has changed in [Finch 0.11](https://github.com/finagle/finch/releases/tag/0.11). Just change your `body` call to `body[CT, Foo]` (where `CT` is content-type) and you should get that compiled. One thing: `String` body is sort of a special case, so you might want to use `stringBody` (no type parameters) instead since `body` is biased towards decoding a payload with a given JSON/XML/whatever decoder.

```
scala> import io.finch._, io.finch.circe._

scala> s(Input.post("/").withBody[Application.Json](Map("foo" -> "bar"))).awaitValueUnsafe()
res2: Option[String] = Some({"foo":"bar"})
```

Comment: Thank you. After removing one library and updating, and making changes to my models, I got it to compile. :)